# Open WPF Window in StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently busy with WPF.
I know that in winforms we can open a form in a panel, which is relatively easy to do.
But how do we do that in WPF?
My WPF Main Window now has three items in it, namely: Navigation[DockPanel], Content[StackPanel] and this StackPanel is inside anotehr DockPanel...
Navigation has a button in it. When I click this button, I want another WPF window to open inside the Content, which is a stackpanel.
Is this possible in WPF?
It does not matter if its XAML or C# code for WPF, i just want to know where to start and how to achieve it.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: This may sound snide, but I don't have a Windows machine here to test: Did you just try it? It might not work, but I wouldn't be surprised if you could just do something like `stack.Children.Add(new TheWindow())`. If that specifically doesn't work, you can create a control that is used both by your window and inserted into your panel.

Comment: Hi Frederik, I started to write an answer then realized it was almost the exact same as another answer I had written a while back, so I marked this one as a duplicate to that one. If the linked post isn't what you're looking for, let me know :)